# Setting up ccache in Ubuntu

Tags: bash

I am currently following the guide to setting up and compiling AOSP in Ubuntu. The problem is I do not have the best knowledge of Linux/Ubuntu.

The part that currently has me confused is setting up the ccache found at this link https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html.

What I don't really understand is the following, which .bashrc file do I need to edit/add the information to? And can I have more than 1 .bashrc file in Ubuntu? Not really sure what this file really does.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is a file which is called by bash before on each start of a new shell.
This file can be used to setup the environment, export variables, create aliases and functions. There are usually multiple copy of this file, One per system and one per user to allow system wide configuration but also customization by users ( users bashrc will be called at last and can overwrite things).

here you edid or add line to your won user's `.bashrc` file
type `cd $HOME` 
`vi .bashrc`
after that change your file and then you have to compile the file using one of the commands.

```
..bashrc 
    or
source .bashrc
```